# there are 35 button on the screen.this means i need to create 35 viewController file on my project

Tags: ios, objective-c

As you can see, there are 35 buttons on the screen. This means I need to create 35 view controllers in my project. I know its stupid，and I know There must be some good solution, but I don't know it.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't mean that you need to create 35 view controllers, it means that you need to create 1 view controller that you can re-use with different data.

Comment: yes ,i know that.but My doubts  is the layout of each view is different.but now i just have one view controller,That is to say,i need to create 35 View?

Comment: I can't answer how many elements you need, it depends on the layout of the view controllers after pressing a button. If every layout is unique in every way after pressing a button, then you might actually need 35 different view controllers, but that is rarely the case. Try to match elements and build dynamic views that you can populate with data.

Comment: OK，THANKS VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider `UICollectionView`.

The UICollectionView class manages an ordered collection of data items and presents them using customizable layouts. Collection views provide the same general function as table views except that a collection view is able to support more than just single-column layouts.

`UICollectionViewCell` : Your Button will be a subclass of UICollectionViewCell.You can easily customize that.

[Implement UICollectionView](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)